# How to Convert C code to Assembly for Freestyle for 9S12?

Tags: assembly

I have started an introductory assembly course and have an assignment to create instructions to do the following.

T=H&~J

The C code associated with this is as follows:

```
void main(void)
{
ddrh = 0x00;
ddrj = 0x00;
ddrt = 0xff;

while(1)
{
ptt = (~ptj)&pth;
}
}
```

DDR's are directional registers to set the i/o.

PT's are the ports.

Any suggestions or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

*Update Assembly Code using MC9S12C32

```
   DDRH equ $0262
   DDRJ equ $026A
   DDRT equ $0242
   PTT  equ $0240
   PTH  equ $0260
   PTJ  equ $0268
        org $4000

   main ldaa #$00
        staa DDRH ;Setting direction register H for all inputs
        ldaa #$00
        staa DDRJ ;Setting direction register J for all inputs.
        ldaa #$FF
        staa DDRT ;Setting direction register T for all outputs.

   loop ldaa PTH  ;load port h to register a
        ldab PTJ  ;load port j to register b
        comb      ;compliment register b contents for ~J
        andb PTH  ;AND logical register b and port H
        stab PTT  :output register b to port T
        bra  loop
        org  $FFFE
        fdb  main
```

The code assebmles with no errors, but when I run it to simulate the processor I receive the following error code:

"Store using EAR W 0x0262 0x00 to I/O port 0x4002 staa $0262 write to unimplemented I/O port 0x0262."

Would anyone be able to check where this is goofing and possibly provide heavy handed suggestions to fix this?

UPDATE! found my issue, wrong processor being selected in the assembler. Have to use MC9S12DP512  and not MC9S12C32.

Comment: A converter from C to assembler is usually called a C compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Because - as far as I understand - this is the homework for your course I will not give you too much help. You should do your homework yourself because otherwise you will not be prepared for the exam.

You should first analyze what the C program is doing. Because you are not doing a C course I can give you a bit of help here:

- It writes the value 0 to the register DDRH
- It writes the value 0 to the register DDRJ
- It writes the value 0xFF (= 255) to the register DDRT
- In an endless loop it does the following steps:
- It reads in the register PTJ
- It inverts the value just read in
- It reads in the register PTH
- It performs an AND combination of both values
- It writes the result to the PTT register
- At the end of a loop a branch/jump instruction to the first instruction of the loop is (always) necessary in assembly code

Now you have to do all these steps in an assembly program. I'm sure you know all necessary instructions from your course.

By the way: You probably wanted to write "Freescale", not "Freestyle"

Comment: Definitely meant to write Freescale.

Comment: Martin, sounds like you may be well versed in this. I have tried my assembly code for this and the assembler is returning errors. Using a MC9S12C32 microcontroller. Will have the code updated on the original question. Perhaps a kick in the head would help to bridge the connection to have this make sense to me. Got your boots on?